# How to mock MongoDB repository method in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I'm trying to mock the following piece of code in my JUnit test

```
requestData = requestRepository.findByRequestId(requestId);
```

by doing

```
@Mock
RequestRepository requestRepository;

@Mock
RequestData requestData;

Mockito.when(requestRepository.findByRequestId(requestId)).thenReturn(requestData);
```

But instead of giving the mock object back, i'm getting null value. 
What is the correct way to mock MongoDB repository methods.

Comment: this is the correct way. Probably you `requestId` value during test execution is not the same as the one used to mock call.

Comment: But instead of giving the mock requestData object, its going to the mongodb and fetching data from there. I want it to send back the mock object.

Comment: I see `@Mock` will work only if you call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` or if you are using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`. If your test is going directly to the db is because probably you are running with `SpringRunner` which is starting your full application, and this is actually an integration test

Comment: Yes I'm running with **SpringRunner** So is there anyway to get mock object instead of actual data from db.

Comment: use `@MockBean`

Comment: Can you share you full code of the junit test case.

Comment: @JuanRada '@MockBean' worked!! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using **SpringRunner** based test, use `@MockBean` to declare mock of your context beans.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know about your request id value (it may be a dynamic value) on that case you can use `Mock.any(<?>.class)`.

**Example:**

```
Mockito.when(requestRepository.findByRequestId(Long.class)).thenReturn(requestData);
```

The above example is only for requestId of type `Long`, if you need integer then you need to change the class to `Integer`.